# Timeout error while running apache2 on port 8080 with Django behind Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, apache2

I'm trying to set up a Django server on Ubuntu 12.04 (on an Amazon EC2 machine).

Following the advice of the docs, I've successfully set up Nginx to serve static files, and am having it forward anything that doesn't begin with /static/ to Apache on port 8080.

However, all requests made to this port connect, but then timeout.

e.g.

```
$ wget http://localhost:8080/
--2013-06-14 00:16:31--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ^C
```

And the response never comes.

Nginx logs report the request being sent upstream to localhost:8080, but nothing ever comes back, and there's nothing /var/log/apach2/*

If I run python manage.py runserver 8080, it works fine - the static files get served by Nginx, and Django serves the rest.

When I originally ran Apache on port 80, it worked fine, but no static content.

I only modified 3 files for Apache2: httpd.conf, ports.conf, and sites-enabled/000-default

**httpd.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/fingerprints_server/Fingerprints_django/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/fingerprints_server

<Directory /home/ubuntu/fingerprints_server/Fingerprints_django>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

**ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080 # used to be NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 8080 # used to be Listen 80
```

**sites-enabled/000-default**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080> # First line, used to be <VirtualHost *:80>
```

As far as I know there's no internal firewalls - iptables had no rules listed. I have a firewall configured with EC2 that opens port 80, and incidentally 8080 while trying to debug this problem. netstat -lntp shows that apache2 listens on port 8080.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason not to eliminate Apache and have [nginx forward the django requests to a WSGI application server](http://www.panta.info/blog/3/how-to-install-and-configure-nginx-uwsgi-and-django-on-ubuntu.html)?

Comment: just that it's what the docs told me to do...

Comment: Actually, I ended up switching to nginx/uwsgi as you suggested, it's much better/simpler. Thanks